# Riak Data Types and Search

Tags: erlang, riak, riak-search

I'm using Riak 2.0.2 and Riak-Erlang-Client 2.0.0 The documentation suggest that "Search is preferred for querying", here the [full excerpt](http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/application-guide/) :

> In general, you should consider Search to be the default choice for
>   nearly all querying needs that go beyond basic CRUD/KV operations. If
>   your use case demands some sort of querying mechanism and you're in
>   doubt about what to use, you should assume that Search is the right
>   tool for you.

There is extensive documentation on how to use Riak Datatype, set-up bucket type, creating search index and so on. I was hoping to see riak client example on http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/search/search-data-types/ but i found none.

I try the following path.

Creating a bucket type that both uses Riak datatype and contains search index

```
riak-admin bucket-type create counters '{"props":{"datatype":"counter"}}' 
riak-admin bucket-type activate counters
curl -XPUT $RIAK_HOST/search/index/scores \
  -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  -d '{"schema":"_yz_default"}'
riak-admin bucket-type update counters '{"props":{"search_index":"scores"}}'
```

Used code in app.

```
Counter = riakc_counter:new().
ChristopherHitchensCounter = riakc_counter:increment(5, Counter).

{ok, Pid} = riakc_pb_socket:start("127.0.0.1",8087).
ChristopherHitchens = riakc_obj:new({<<"counters">>, <<"people">>}, <<"christopher_hitchens">>,
    ChristopherHitchensCounter,
    "application/riak_counter"),
riakc_pb_socket:put(Pid, ChristopherHitchens).
```

At this point, i expect i could query some counter using

```
{ok, Results} = riakc_pb_socket:search(Pid, <<"scores">>, <<"counter:[* TO 15]">>),
io:fwrite("~p~n", [Results]),
Docs = Results#search_results.docs,
io:fwrite("~p~n", [Docs]).
```

But it doesn't seems to be working. Any guide on this would be appreciated.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

In case someone stumbling upon similar issue (until Riak documentation includes example for erlang client on http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/search/search-data-types/), the guy from riak mailing list provides [link to riak test suite](https://github.com/basho/riak_test/blob/master/tests/yz_crdt.erl#L33), and its turned out that `riakc_pb_socket:update_type/4` is the required method to associate riak data type. I modify previous used code to :

```
Counter = riakc_counter:new().
ChristopherHitchensCounter = riakc_counter:increment(5, Counter).

{ok, Pid} = riakc_pb_socket:start("127.0.0.1",8087).
riakc_pb_socket:update_type(Pid,{<<"counters">>,<<"people">>},<<"christopher_hitchens">>,riakc_counter:to_op(ChristopherHitchensCounter)).
```

And now i can perform search query on my indexes :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Counters and other data types are not manipulated via riakc_obj. Refer to the documentation page here http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/using/data-types/ and select the "Erlang" tab on examples.

Comment: I'm stuck on `Counters/Sets/Maps in the Erlang client are opaque data structures that collect operations as you mutate them. We will associate the data
structure with a bucket type, bucket, and key later on.` part. How do we save it on some bucket then? Thanks for response btw.

Comment: I finally found `riakc_pb_socket:update_type/4,5` on link you've pointed above. Would be helpful if it's also mentioned at http://docs.basho.com/riak/latest/dev/search/search-data-types/